# Using multiple global error files in the same solution (Web Application)

Tags: c#, .net, global-asax

I have an Web application with 3 sub folders that I want to use in the solution:

1. HR
2. Business
3. Money

Each has a sub application that uses common parts of the solution like Master Page, CSS, etc.
Each application has its own error page in their respective folders.

But there is only 1 Global.asax at the top folder. 
I want to handle error at global level for each application so that the unknown errors always land up at the correct error page for each solution when we are browsing their pages.

Eg. 
1. Error in /HR/Page1.aspx goes to /HR/ErrorPageForHR.aspx
2. Error in /Business/Page1.aspx goes to /Business/ErrorPageForBusiness.aspx
3. Error in /Money/Page1.aspx goes to /Money/ErrorPageForMoney.aspx

How can I achieve this ?
Can I make multiple Global.asax in each folder or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viable approach is to have the logic of your error handler into a `Class Library` with a Class to handle the error accordingly. This project could also be useful for ther common behaviors shared across the 3 web applications. Then Add that library as reference to each web application, and within each `Global.asax` file, on the backend, include the `Class Library` project main namespace and call your `ErrorHandler` Class logic. That is what I would do...

Comment: This sounds like a good approach that I can use in other projects as well. The class library can log the errors and also redirect me to the correct error page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple Global.asax, unless you convert folders to Areas which is probebly overkill.

You can get request with HttpContext.Current.Request and redirect user to proper error page based in URL.

Additionally, you can put different web.config file in each folder with customeErrors for 404, 403.

Comment: Thats cool, I can find out the erroring sub application using the HTTP Request (HttpContext.Current.Request)  and use the class approach above to make it reusable :-)